# Are there any cons for installing hardwood floor room by room instead of all the floor at once?

Tags: flooring

This is about the main floor, around 1000sqft.The floor is an elongated rectangle with a third for the living which is wall to wall at one end of the rectangle and then a long hallway along the long axis of the floor with rooms kitche and bathroom on one side or the other.
I have the option to wait for an installer to do all the work around November or start doing it myself room by room starting with the smallest room at the other end of the floor, oposite to living. I k ow you have to start parallel with the longest run on the floor so in my case I could run aline of hardwood floor pieces from that room throught the hallway all the way to the other end of the floor in the living
Are there any caveats for this plan? (I can buy the hardwood in advance, all at once)

Comment: actual hardwood or "engineered"

Comment: actual hardwood is what I would like. As far as I understand there is no price difference. I do know that the engineered one is more stable but the actual one can be refinished more than once

Comment: Sounds like a hall plus two or three rooms, all done as a single unbroken(if in pieces) floor(no thresholds at doorways).  One big con will be measurements must be perfect, a small mistake will grow.

Comment: yes that would be the plan. Can you detail on the errors you have in mind ?

Comment: Are the hallway walls and the far walls(from the hallway) of the rooms exactly parallel?  If yes, are you sure?   I think I would start with the hallway into the living room, then the smaller rooms.  Laser/caulk lines will be your friend.

Comment: Well that is a good point but hey I already have old hardwood floor in place narrow strips. So if they did it it means it is doable and it should not be a challenge. It is creaking like hell. No subfloor...needs fixing

Comment: We have a similar problem with a creaking floor... I'm considering two routes: attempting to insert a bit of graphite powder (preferably in place, slightly demounted if necessary), or waxing the connecting parts with simple paraffin (from the butt end of a candle). The latter would definitely require dismantling of the floor though.

Comment: I am removing it there is no question about it. It is 60y old and it does that everywhere  if I do what you said it is the same amount of work

Comment: Apart from the creaking, what is the general state of the floor? It's been mentioned in past threads about hardwood floors, but if in good quality, relaying and sanding an old floor (with one of the anticreak measures above) really adds to both the atmosphere and eventual sale price of a house.

Comment: Neah I want something new, more modern look. My house is not like it is some heritage house or something that it is worth preserving the time marks on it, just regular suburban house